# Is there a known closed form for these polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, closed-form

The polynomials are like:

$P_0 = 1\\ P_1 = -2+4x\\P_2 = 8-32x+16x^2\\P_3=-48 + 288 x - 288 x^2 + 64 x^3$

?

I have checked Legendre, Chebyshev, Hermite... Any help will be appreciated!

---

This comes from:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy\; e^{iky} e^{-y^2/4} H_m(x+y/2)H_m(x-y/2)$

where, for polynomials, I did a replacement x=x^2+k^2.

Comment: Where do these come from?

Comment: These are the results of the integration. I can add it to the question. One sec.

Comment: There are some two-index families that allow such recurrence. Yours seems $P_{n+2} = 4x P_{n+1}- 6 P_n$   or similar

Comment: There's no $k$ in your polynomials.

Comment: @Angina Seng, sorry, right, corrected.

Comment: @Will Jagy I tried, starting from P_3 they stop working. I failed figuring out the exact polynomial for such two-index family. Do you have an idea? It is not Hermite...

Comment: It would help if you worked out $P_4$ and $P_5$ and edited them in. There need not be a name for these; however, we can work out an explicit recursion under some circumstances. The two most likely are linear degree 2 and linear full size, by which I mean $P_{n+1}$ is a linear combination of $P_0, P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ with a possible dependence of the coefficients on $n$

Comment: @Will Jagy Thank you! Give me a day, I will update this post with 4th and 5th order and ping you here.